# how to store logs into mysql db using express-winston in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, winston

I am trying to store logs into mysql db(with Sequelize) using express-winston in Node.js.

According to doc(https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-sql-transport), I should do the following:

```
const { Logger } = require('winston');
const { SQLTransport } = require('./../lib/winston-sql-transport');   
 
const logger = new Logger({
  transports: [
    new SQLTransport({
      tableName: 'winston_logs',
    })]
});
 
module.exports = logger;
```

I apply above code in app.js, but not successful.

app.js

```
const { SQLTransport } = require('./../lib/winston-sql-transport'); // //Error: Cannot find module './../lib/winston-sql-transport'

const mysqlOption =  {
   tableName: 'winston_logs'
}

app.use(
  expressWinston.logger({
    transports: [
      new SQLTransport(mysqlOption)
    ],
    format: winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.timestamp({ format: timezoned }),
      winston.format.json(),
    ),
    metaField: null,
    expressFormat: true, 
    statusLevels: false,
    level: function (req, res) {
      var level = "";
      if (res.statusCode < 400) { level = "info"; }
      if (res.statusCode >= 400) { level = "warn"; }
      if (res.statusCode >= 500) { level = "error"; }
      return level;
    }
  })
)
```

I tried to change the import to `const { SQLTransport } = require('winston-sql-transport');`
Resulting error:

```
Error: You have to define client

at new SQLTransport (/server/node_modules/winston-sql-transport/lib/winston-sql-transport.js:40:13)
```

I found that people rarely talk about this package.
So I wonder if there is any way to do it?

**Update 1:**

I updated `mysqlOption` as suggested by the comment

```
const { SQLTransport } = require('winston-sql-transport'); 

const mysqlOption =  {
  tableName : "winston_logs",
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host: '127.0.0.1:3306',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'mydb'
  }
}
```

The logs successfully appear in Console, but nothing store in my database.

**Update 2:**

Since I am using Sequelize, I'm going to provide the schema for the logs table

```
// See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/
// for more of what you can do here.
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const logs = sequelizeClient.define('winston_logs', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    level: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false
    },
    message: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    meta: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false
    },
    hostname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false
    },
    timestamp: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    }
  });

  logs.associate = function (models) {
  };

  return logs;
};
```

Comment: Well they didn't do a good job when writing the docs. If you look into the source code you should be able to figure out what's wrong. Hint: `mysqlOption = { tableName: 'winston_logs', client: 'mysql', connection: { host: '...', user: '...', password: '...', database: '...' } }` https://github.com/ofkindness/winston-sql-transport/blob/master/lib/winston-sql-transport.js

Comment: @Molda I updated the code above, can you please take a look?

Comment: I just noticed that the package has not been updated in last 3 years. I think it's time to find another package. The log function in the package expects 4 args but the same function in winston file logger expects only 2. First is string and should be object see [this](https://github.com/ofkindness/winston-sql-transport/blob/master/lib/winston-sql-transport.js#L85) and [this](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/lib/winston/transports/file.js#L117)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally giving up to store logs in mysql db, since mysql transport package seems a bit outdated.

Instead, I store the logs locally, using `winston-daily-rotate-file`
It can set the frequency of rotation, Maximum size of the file etc.

link: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file